# Vim substitute string for same format string but different names

Tags: vim, vi, substitution

File looks like:

```
INSERT INTO x VALUES (48394, '9-10-2007', 19);
INSERT INTO x VALUES (99981, '3-5-2008', 45);
```

I would like to replace each line with:

```
INSERT INTO x VALUES (48394, STR_TO_DATE('9-10-2007', %d-%m-%y), 19);
INSERT INTO x VALUES (99981, STR_TO_DATE('3-5-2008', %d-%m-%y), 45);
```

I can't seem to find how to deal with changing string names to replace

```
:%s/<WHAT GOES HERE>/add in STR_TO_DATE(...)/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is structured exactly like that with no other strings delimited by `'` and the contents are always the date you want to convert, searching for simply `'.*'` will work:

```
:%s/'.*'/STR_TO_DATE(&, %d-%m-%y)
```

To be more specific, i.e. if other strings appear on the same line:

```
:%s/'\d*-\d*-\d*'/STR_TO_DATE(&, %d-%m-%y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a solution:

`:%s/\(INSERT INTO x VALUES (.*,\) '\(.*\)'\(.*\)/\1 STR_TO_DATE('\2', %d-%m-%y)\3/g`

[Relevant reading](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)